# Possible errors when reading larger lines

Tags: c, linux, search, grep

I noticed a problem with the next line `while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {`: I may get errors if the lines read are too large. Should I read `MAXLINE` pieces? I think it's a problem if I break the original line into pieces. It is possible to "cut" the fixed line in the middle of the word I am looking for.

For example, if you break the `car for sale` (you are looking `for` ) in `car fo` and `r sale`. I will not find `for` in either of the two pieces. Maybe a solution would be for each part read, to read extra `len (search_word)` characters (without changing the original place where the next piece would have started). Basically I read more `r s` in the first part, but it guarantees that I will find `for`

How can I handle possible errors?

The following program is based on the implementation of grep from linux, doing a search for several words

program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Usages:\n1: ./grep.o <word> <file>\n2: ./grep.o -e <word> [-e "
               "<word>...] <file>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        FILE *fp;
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;
        int i;

        fp = fopen(argv[argc - 1], "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("File doesn't exist or cannot be read!\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (argc == 3)
        {
            while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
            {
                if (strstr(line, argv[1]) != NULL)
                    printf("%s", line);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 1; i < argc - 2; i += 2)
            {
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "-e") != 0)
                {
                    printf("The option must be \"-e\"!\n");
                    fclose(fp);
                    return 1;
                }
            }

            if (i + 1 == argc - 1)
            {
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "-e") != 0)
                {
                    printf("The option must be \"-e\"!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("The option must have a word after it!\n");
                }
                fclose(fp);
                return 1;
            }
            while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
            {
                for (i = 1; i < argc - 2; i += 2)
                {
                    if (strstr(line, argv[i + 1]) != NULL)
                    {
                        printf("%s", line);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            fclose(fp);
            if (line)
                free(line);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @wohlstad No, [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) returns `ssize_t`. How would you check for `-1` with [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: What problem did you notice? An error? Unexpected result or behavior? Add the input, actual output and/or error messages and expected output to your question.

Comment: @Oka - sure, my mistake. I tried to fix the indentation in MSVC and the compiler complained about ssize_t. Didn't check it further.

Comment: What you describe – a line might be read in several chunks – seems to be a problem with `fgets`, where you read into a fixed buffer, but not with `getline`, which (re-)allocates memory for you. Do you have example input that fails?

Comment: I edited the program

Comment: Please don't describe the compiler error, copy&paste the complete error message to your question *as text* and make sure it is clear which line of your code the message refers to.

Comment: I didn't get an error. I just asume this is a posibile problem. Maybe I was wrong

Comment: The only potential problem is the length of a line from `<file>` exceeding available memory, which seems improbable. Otherwise, `line` will grow to hold variably sized lines. Unless you want to support [`pcregrep --multiline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pcregrep.1.html) functionality, this program seemingly works fine.

Comment: one question: at line `if (strcmp (argv [i]," -e ")! = 0) {` is it better to use `getopt` and derivatives to treat better (and clearer logic)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo [`getline(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html): *"... before calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.  If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary. ..."*. The buffer should grow if `len` is inadequate: https://godbolt.org/z/6e8bsTqex This does mean one overly long line, once encountered, among many short lines will make the program consume maximal memory for a given file, though.

Comment: @Oka You are correct. I missed that crucial part. Thanks! I removed my ill-adviced comment.

Comment: Yes, make use of `getopt()` for better code.

Comment: @Lorand Yes, using `getopt` would be better (collect `-e` operands in a data structure of some kind). Overall this question isn't really suited for Stack Overflow, as it is asking for improvements / refactoring to a functional program. I'll hesitantly suggest https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but you will want to frame your question more clearly, and improve your understanding of your own code, as they generally expect higher quality submissions than SO. Alternatively, try rephrasing this question to focus in on your misunderstanding of `getline` breaking up lines (which it does not).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe is not present in your code precisely because you use `getline()` instead of `fgets()`. `getline()` reallocates the `line` pointer and `len` as required to read a full line. The only limitation is memory, which is unlikely to pose a problem on current systems.

Note however that you should close the file and free `line` outside of the `else` branch to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: thanks for your time. Indeed, case if you have errors if the lines are too large it is very unlikely to be encountered, but the idea is that it can happen. If current systems have more resources, you will never want a trivial program to use them all. In addition, there are specific cases where resources are very limited